# Better Performance Linq To SQl query

Tags: vb.net, performance, linq-to-sql

Is there a way to increase the fetching performance of my LINQ to SQL query where its total count is more than a hundred thousand? Should I separate  the total data to 5 parts by using skip or take? My query, when fetching, took more than 40 minutes.

```
   Dim query = From a In context.Orders
                        Join b In context.Status On a.OrderItem Equals b.OrderItem
                        Join c In context.Summary On a.OrderItem.Substring(0, 16) Equals c.OrderSuffix
                        Where Not (b.Status.Contains("E")) And a.Type = "AG" And a.OrderItem = b.OrderItem And a.OrderItem.Substring(0, 16) = c.OrderSuffix
                        Order By a.OrderItem.Substring(0, 16), a.Agn Ascending
                        Select a.OrderItem,
                        JobOr = a.auftrag_nr.Substring(0, 16),
                        Suffix = (a.auftrag_nr.Substring(0, 16).Substring(13)),
                        a.Agn,
                        a.Base,
                        b.Status,
                        a.Group,
                        a.Machine,
                        a.Article,
                        a.Height,
                        a.Sol, c.plan, a.DatePlanned
```

Comment: You need to ask yourself what use 100,000 records would be anyway. The user isn't going to be able handle that many at a time. What are you actually doing with the data?

Comment: Users have access to database, provided by the developers of the windows app they are currently using. I don't know why they provided it.

These users would like to create daily reports. They put SQL queries, provided by the app developers, and executing it directly on SQL server.

I wanna create an app for them to just have a one-click button to generate all reports for them.

Comment: Questions about improving performance can't be answered without sufficient details of *all* involved parts. Which generally means: can't be answered. See also: [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: I have, like, 8 linq-to-sql queries. And I am putting these data a worksheet of excel per query. Currently using closedXML and interop.excel. I also put it in a list of task and used Task.WhenAll(tasks.toarray). My report generatopn would take more than hour

Comment: Is it an issue of the Linq query or something else? Where is the database running from? It could be latency issues transporting that many records across the wire. If you make the query a stored procedure and call that from your code, do you get the same/similar performance issues?

Comment: One thing that almost certainly kills performance is these non-sargable `Substring` expressions in joins and order-by clauses. And of course it's nonsense to return > 100,000 records, even for reports. What's the point of generating a daily report that's 99.99% identical to yesterday's report?

Comment: Btw. did you create useful indices on your database and did you turn off the ObjectTracking and this stuff?

Comment: @GertArnold The point of some actions are often not that pointful. A friend of mine has to implement a solution to digitalize data from papers that was just printed before from digital data and because the data are never alowed to exist multiple times he don't get access to the digital data. Sounds bulls***? yes! So discussing about it doesn't worth it ;)

Comment: The App developers game them the SQL queries. I just convert it to linq-to-sql without adding dateField or anything. Thus, the hundred thousand of data. I don't wanna second guess what is the date field.

Comment: What I just set for my new Context is ObjectTrackingEnabled to False.

Comment: The database is not created by my team. We can't alter it. We don't want to alter it. Total count so far is 27 million of data. So, we just use SELECT query.

Comment: I found a nice article by Erland Sommarskog about the topic: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Answer (score -1):

Actually you make a really big join, which you filter afterwards.

If you have a filter like a.type = "AG" than you should apply it before you join, so many unnecessary join results will not be even generated.

Another idea for you: 
The other style of writing linq queries. 
like:

```
dim foo as IQueryable(Of TypeInYourTable) = yourDBContext.yourTable.where(function(v) v.a = ...).SomeOtherLinqFunctions...
```

In this way you can build up the queriables for each table and filter them first (e.g. the a.type = "AG"), then you can use the .Join(...) function and make proper joins, where you not just compare one pair of values of two datasets.

Be aware, that as long as the Queryable is a Queryable, no call was made to the database. You need to call e.g. .ToArray() or .ToList() or ... to enforce the call.
If you don't and you return a Queryable, then close the context of it and then try to get the results of the Queryable you will get a runtime exception.

Comment: The place of the filter doesn't matter. Everything is translated into SQL and the SQL builder applies its own build order and then the database's query optimizer determines the best query plan.

Comment: @GertArnold This is not exactly correct, that the optimizer determines the _best_ plan. "it makes an estimate of what may be best way to execute the query" from 2.2 http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: The point is that the position of the `where` clause in the LINQ statement doesn't matter for the generated SQL (just try it yourself in a LINQ-to-SQL query) and *if* it did database would probably be able to optimize the query.

Comment: @GertArnold I would love to get a prove or a documentation for that, since it would help me, too.

Comment: I don't think Microsoft documented the inner workings of LINQ-to-SQL anywhere. Just try a LINQ-to-SQL query and position a where clause before and after a join: the generated SQL is identical.